# GridView stays empty

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView with one ImageView and one TextView below in each cell.

The logic works well. I make a reference to my GridView, set Columns and set a Adapter. During that i have a thread which set's the Images and their Name to a List. (One DrawAble List for Images and one String List for the Labels). To satisfy my users, i want to update the GridView while the thread is adding the Images and Labels to the Lists.

But the Update only works if i provide nasty static variables. (I hate them). OR if i set the Adapter new to the GridView everytime an update has occured. (This is also nasty because you are not able to scroll the GridView during ist update..)

This is my CustomAdapter:

```
public CustomAdapter(DialogBox dialogBoxActivity,List<Drawable> imported_scaled_images, List<String> imported_labels, int position) {
    this.context = dialogBoxActivity;
    this.scaledImage = imported_scaled_images.toArray(new Drawable[imported_scaled_images.size()]);
    this.labels = imported_labels.toArray(new String[imported_labels.size()]);
    this.used_cells = position;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public void updateGrid(List<Drawable> imported_scaled_images, List<String> imported_labels, int position) {
    this.scaledImage = imported_scaled_images.toArray(new Drawable[imported_scaled_images.size()]);
    this.labels = imported_labels.toArray(new String[imported_labels.size()]);
    this.used_cells = position;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.e("update","true");
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.e("notify","true");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return used_cells;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder {

    ImageView img;
    TextView tv;

    public Holder(ImageView img, TextView tv) {
        this.img = img;
        this.tv = tv;
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView img;
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv_abc;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter_view_layout, null);
        img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        tv =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        //tv_abc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_normal_portrait_abc);
        convertView.setTag(new Holder(img,tv));
    } else {
        Holder holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        img = holder.img;
        tv = holder.tv;
        //tv_abc = holder.tv_abc;

    }
            img.setImageDrawable(scaledImage[position]);
            tv.setText(labels[position]);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    return convertView;
}
```

}

And on my Activity i have the updateGrid and i call it in a TimerTask on MainThread:

```
private void updateGrid() {
    customAdapter.updateGrid(images, labels, position);
}
```

What's Happening is that the GridView stays empty. Maybe it's because Position is 0 while im Setting the baseadapter to the gridview. But this can't be the Problem because when i'm updating it should recognize the new size in getCount(). Once again, the logic works well. Images where added and the methods updateGrid and notiyDataSetChanged are called as i want to. But the GridView stays like, i don't like showing These Images.(completely empty).

Hope something can provide a good solution. I appreciate every help and every improvement of the code i posted above.(regarding to Performance or whatever). Thank you!

Update: Position  is my variable which Counts the cells which are available. Because some cells are empty(=null). Due to that i don't know how much cells will be filled(because i sort the Images alphabetically(for each row => some cells are filled with null) i can't provide the BaseAdapters getCount method a number before my logic hasn't finished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCount return total no item count not any position :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imported_scaled_images.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Response. As you can see imported_scaled_Images is only available in the constructor or in the updateGrid method. But whats available is scaledImages (the Array which gets his data from imported_scaled_Images). So i put into the getCount method: `scaledImage.length`.. but the Problem stays the same. GridView stays empty. Andy other suggestions? @Haresh Chhelana

Comment: @MMike,try maintain local ToalItemCoounter in adapter and updated value when update grid data also return ToalItemCoounter value in getCount()